# Единобразие отображения сайта в разных браузерах

Tags: jquery, php, css, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой как разное отображения сайта в разных браузерах. В частности, беспокоит то, что в некоторых из них некоторые компоненты вовсе не отображаются (input элементы).

**Вот как отображается сайт в Opera и Firefox** (самый корректный вариант):

[image]

Как видите, формы и кнопки округлые. Input (типа radiobutton), input(типа checkbox) и input (типа text) в таблице отображаются нормально. И скрипт показывающий скрытые поля input (типа text) по нажатию ческбоксов (расположенных справа в таблице) работает корректно.

Теперь **пример-скрин как в хроме ведет себя сайт**:

[image]

Как видите input (и radiobutton, и checkbox, и text) не отображаются вовсе... Управлять данными естественно невозможно при таком раскладе дел.

**И скрин сайта в браузере IE**

[image]

Все input отображаются, кроме input (типа text), которые должны по нажатию галочки справа отображаться. И соответственно нельзя менять ФИО граждан, так как input (типа text) не появляется по клику галочки.

Как решить эту проблему, чтобы по возможности сделать доступным все компоненты в разных браузерах.

Вот CSS отвечающий за оформление input:

```
input {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input [name="fam_edit"],
input [name="name_edit"],
input [name="date_edit"]
{
    border: solid;
    background: #FFFbb8;    
}

input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; }
input[type="button"] {
    border: none;
    background: #1dabb8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
}
 input[type="button"]:hover { background: #198d98; }
```

Поясню **input** с именами **[name="`fam_edit`"]**, **[name="`name_edit`"]** и **[name="`date_edit`"]** это поля скрытые input'ы (фамилия, имя и дата рождения человека) которые отображаются по клику на ческбокс (справа в таблице).

**Кусок кода формирования таблицы** (на php):

```
<td>".$value['id']."</td>
              <td><span name='fam_text[".$value['id']."]'>".$value['fam_people']."</span>
                  <input type='text' name='fam_edit[".$value['id']."]' value='".$value['fam_people']."' style='display:none'>
              </td>
              <td><span name='name_text[".$value['id']."]'>".$value['name_people']."</span>
                  <input type='text' name='name_edit[".$value['id']."]' value='".$value['name_people']."' style='display:none'>
              </td>
              <td><span name='date_text[".$value['id']."]'>".date($format_date_word, strtotime($value['date_born_people']))."</span>
                  <input type='text' name='date_edit[".$value['id']."]' value='".date($format_date_word, strtotime($value['date_born_people']))."' style='display:none'>
              </td>
              <th><center><input type='checkbox' name='edit_button' value='$value[id]'></center></th>
              <th><center><input type='checkbox' name='delete_button' value='$value[id]'></center></th>
```

Как вы заметили наверное в каждую ячейку таблицы заносится видимая текстовая переменная обрамленная в тег span и скрытое input поле тоже с текстом и стилем `style='display:none'`. Это делается для того чтобы манипулировать данными, при нажатии/отпускании ческбоксов скрывать и показывать поочередно их (переводя то в режим чтения, то в режим редактирования поля записей таблицы).

И **JavaScript-код** (с использованием jquery) отвечающий за сокрытие/раскрытие полей input типа текст(в таблице):

```
// Вход/выход в режим редактирования     
             $("input[name=edit_button]").live("change", function()
             {
                 var checkElements=document.getElementsByName("edit_button");
                 for(var i=0; i<checkElements.length; i++)
                 {
                    checkElement = checkElements[i];
                    if (checkElement.checked==1)
                    {
                       //alert('Нажали флажок '+i);
                       document.getElementsByName("fam_text["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'none';
                       document.getElementsByName("fam_edit["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'block';
                       document.getElementsByName("name_text["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'none';
                       document.getElementsByName("name_edit["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'block';
                       document.getElementsByName("date_text["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'none';
                       document.getElementsByName("date_edit["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'block';                     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //alert('Отпустили флажок'+i);
                       document.getElementsByName("fam_text["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'block';
                       document.getElementsByName("fam_edit["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'none';
                       document.getElementsByName("name_text["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'block';
                       document.getElementsByName("name_edit["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'none';
                       document.getElementsByName("date_text["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'block';
                       document.getElementsByName("date_edit["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].style.display = 'none';
                    } 
                 }
              }
              );
```

Элементы document имеющие окончания *`_text` - это span поля (простой текст), а элементы оканчивающиеся на *`_edit` - это input поля (типа текст). С помощью свойства display они поочередно переводятся в видимое/невидимое состояние. Только это в IE почему-то не работает...

Наверное слишком объемный вопрос получился у меня по картинкам и коду, но тем не менее, надеюсь, может кто даст какие-нибудь рекомендации и подсказки, как сделать корректным сайт в браузере хроме и IE?

Comment: первым делом, первым делом валидатор.

Comment: это называется многообразие ошибок и как их интерпретируют разные браузеры.
`input [name="fam_edit"]` - это не "input и с именем", а "input которого дочерний элемент с именем". еще раз. это не ошибки браузеров, а ваши ошибки. исправляйте, воспользуйтесь валидаторами, например. попробуйте пройтись по стилям [helium-css](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) посмотреть какие стили применяются, а какие нет - можно увидеть ошибки в селекторах. ну а с js - в консоль и дебагер в помощь...

Comment: @eicto, у меня jQuery 1.6.4, какую сказали использовать, такую и использую. И в этой версии live не считается еще устаревшим. JQuery используется для других задач, я опустил основную часть кода. @Yura Ivanov, не понял как тогда обратиться к конкретному input у которого name="fam_edit"?

Comment: @IntegralAL, ну пробел у вас лишний, очевидно. попробуйте:

    console.log($("input [name='fam_edit']").length);
    console.log($("input[name='fam_edit']").length);

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, сколько же у вас было терпения изучать всю эту перфоленту!

Answer (score 1):

все просто

> экранируйте кавычки , их слишком много
> или избавьтесь от них